# Firefox won't open on home page

Tags: firefox, windows-vista

I've had Firefox set to open on my home page (google.com) for years.  But suddenly, after some hiccups over the weekend, it now insists on opening what I take to be the default Firefox home page (which is an array of recently used window snapshots).

The home page is still definitely set to Google (I've reset it to be sure, and pressing Home takes me there), and the option to "Show my home page" on startup is set, but I can't find a way to make Firefox use the home page for startup/new windows.  (I've waded through "Options" about 6 times.)

Does anyone have a suggestion?

OK, now I see -- the home page is opening correctly when I start (I'd swear that was not the case yesterday), and I'm getting the "new tab" page, whereas previously I got a blank page.  Pressing the gear icon in the upper right corner (it used to be a waffle) switches to the blank new tab.

So I guess I don't have a problem.  (Only why did the Windoze update somehow muck with Firefox settings?)

Answer (score 0):

OK, now I see -- the home page is opening correctly when I start (I'd swear that was not the case yesterday), and I'm getting the "new tab" page, whereas previously I got a blank page. Pressing the gear icon in the upper right corner (it used to be a waffle) switches to the blank new tab.

So I guess I don't have a problem. (Only why did the Windoze update somehow muck with Firefox settings?)